# Splunk - RSS Scripted Input

Tags: splunk, rss-reader

[image][image]I have downloaded RSS Scripted Input app from Splunk and extracted it to Splunk etc apps

Can you please help me fixing the "NameError: name 'administrator' is not defined" in Splunkd log?

The base_url has been defined, username and password are provided in rssfeed2.py

==============

Comment: You should modify the script (it is not coded to current Best Practices) lines 15 and 16 to reflect your admin account credentials.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Admin credentials are 'administrator' & 'administrator'

Comment: Can you please help me modifying the script?

Comment: The Splunk administrator account name usually is 'admin'.

Comment: yes but i changed it to administrator. Any issues here? please

Comment: splunkd.log seems to think you don't have a user called "administrator".